# SQL update from one Table to another based on a Column

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two tables called **ata** and **sku** and i want to match SKU from ata table and ARTIKEL_NUMBER from sku table to fit weight from ATA (TOTAL_WEIGHT_PIECE) on sku column called Greutate_kg.

[image]
(ATA TABLE)
[image]
(SKU TABLE)
[image]

Comment: Please provide the tables structure, sample data and desired result [mre]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D4DC.png (ATA Table) https://i.stack.imgur.com/IETNA.png (SKU TABLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try next:

```
UPDATE sku
JOIN ata ON ata.ARTIKEL_NUMBER = sku.SKU
SET sku.Greutate_kg = ata. TOTAL_WEIGHT_PIECE
WHERE sku.Greutate_kg IS NULL;
```

Comment: And if it's not NULL how it's work? For example for values in this field.

Comment: `IS NULL` in this case mean only rows without values in `sku` table will be update

Comment: I understand that, but if i want to change a price, IS NULL., and that price not appear.